# Unable to build entity manager factory - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate

im trying to learn JPA, and i've build a maven project. Now i want to test my JPA classes, but when i try to test I get this error : Unable to build entity manager factory, im really new so tell me when i miss something.

[image: This is my project structure:]

my persistence.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
                 version="2.1">

        <persistence-unit name="JEA6">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
            <class>domain.Kweet</class>
            <class>domain.Trend</class>
            <class>domain.User</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://*hidden*/>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="*hidden*"/>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*hidden*"/>


<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My KweetServicesTest

```
import domain.Kweet
import domain.User
import org.testng.annotations.Test
import service.KweetServices

import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
import javax.persistence.Persistence

/**
 * Created by Nick on 08-Mar-17.
 */
class KweetServicesTest extends GroovyTestCase {

KweetServices service;

private final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JEA6");
EntityManager entityManager;
User user1;
User user2;

Kweet tweet1;
Kweet tweet2;

void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    user1 = new User("user1", "password1", "admin");
    entityManager.persist(user1);
    user2 = new User("user2", "password2", "normal");
    entityManager.persist(user2);

    tweet1 = new Kweet("tweet 1", new Date(), user1);
    tweet2 = new Kweet("tweet 2", new Date(), user2);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

void tearDown() {

}

void testCreateUser(){
service.createUser(user1);
}
```

}

The error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51712,suspend=y,server=n -ea -javaagent:C:\Users\Nick\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;D:\IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Nick\Documents\JEA6\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Nick\Documents\JEA6\target\classes;C:\Users\Nick\Documents\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\ejb\api\main\jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\Documents\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\api\main\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\Documents\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\jsp\api\main\jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.20.0-GA\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.0\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\6.0.5\mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\javax\javaee-web-api\7.0\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar;D:\IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4\lib\groovy-all-2.4.6.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\junit\junit\3.8.1\junit-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.11\testng-6.11.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.64\jcommander-1.64.jar;C:\Users\Nick\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 KweetServicesTest
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51712', transport: 'socket'
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:31 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: JEA6
    ...]
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:31 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:31 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:31 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://studmysql01.fhict.local/dbi324529]
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=dbi324529, password=****}
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 08, 2017 7:01:32 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testCreateUser (javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$createEntityManagerFactory.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at KweetServicesTest.<init>(KweetServicesTest.groovy:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:131)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:114)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.createClassOrMethodSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:147)
    at com.intellij.junit3.TestRunnerUtil.getTestSuite(TestRunnerUtil.java:81)
    at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:590)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:57)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1726)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1596)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: studmysql01.fhict.local
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:179)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
    ... 53 more
)

    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:263)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.doRun(TestRunner.java:116)
    at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.doRun(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:113)
    at junit.textui.TestRunner.doRun(TestRunner.java:109)
    at com.intellij.junit3.JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit3IdeaTestRunner.java:45)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51712', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EntityManagerFactory` cannot be created because the underlying driver connection could not be established, and that happened because the hostname in question couldn't be found.

You can see this from this line in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: studmysql01.fhict.local
```

Comment: Ayy I think i have to read the error more carefully next time, thx :D